# Automatic be bold character string?

Tags: wpf, linq, html-agility-pack

On html:
I get a character :
“**The Theory of Everything**,” may have a few more magic tricks up his sleeve. Sources tell Variety that **Redmayne** is the favorite to play **Newt Scamander** in Warner Bros.’ hotly-anticipated “Harry Potter” spin-off, “...

When I will process it by html agility pack(using LINQ) then It be show off:

“The Theory of Everything,” may have a few more magic tricks up his sleeve. Sources tell Variety that Redmayne is the favorite to play Newt Scamander in Warner Bros.’ hotly-anticipated “Harry Potter” spin-off, “...

I want these bold character on html when take down on my app then still keep bold character(or color). Can it be do that?

```
foreach(var pos in pos_block)
                        {
                       //get header, pronunciton
                            var pronuncationuk=pos.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "sound audio_play_button pron-icon uk");
                            var pronuncationus=pos.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "sound audio_play_button pron-icon us");
                            var pos_head = pos.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "pos-head");                               

                            ////
                            ////
                            ////    

                                var id = pos.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "sense-block");
                                if(id!=null)
                                {
                                    foreach(var node in id)
                                    {
                                        result = new ResultToSearch();
                                        var span_h2 = node.Descendants("h2").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "");
                                        var sense_body = node.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "sense-body");
                                        if(j==1)
                                        {
                                            if(section_title!=null)
                                            {
                                                result.vocabulary = section_title.InnerText.Trim();
                                            }
                                            if(pronuncationuk!=null)
                                            {
                                                result.pronunciationuk = pronuncationuk.GetAttributeValue("class","");
                                                result.iconuk = "/Photos/uk.png";
                                            }
                                            if(pronuncationus!=null)
                                            {
                                                result.pronunciationus = pronuncationuk.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
                                                result.iconus = "/Photos/us.png";
                                            }
                                            if(pos_head!=null)
                                            {
                                                result.poshead = pos_head.InnerText.Trim();
                                            }

                                        }
                                        if(span_h2!=null)
                                        {
                                            result.senseblockh2 = span_h2.InnerText.Trim();
                                        }
                                        if(sense_body!=null)
                                        {
                                            result.sensebody = sense_body.InnerText.Trim();
                                        }
                                        arrays.Add(result);
                                    j++;
                                }
                               //

                            }
                             //                                   
                            j=1;
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to grab the html?

Comment: Take a look at the [Documents in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx) article on MSDN. Then you may try to add `Run` and `Bold` objects to the `Inlines` collection of TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Try property `InnerHtml` instead of `InnerText`.

`InnerHtml` gets the HTML between the start and end tags of the object.
Whereas `InnerText` strips all HTML tags and returns the pure text content.

Comment: @jeff ninney: The HTML Agility Pack doesn't offer a "to text" method which ignores all except some tags.

Comment: @jeff ninney: The HTML Agility Pack doesn't offer a "to text" method which ignores all except some tags.

You have at least two options:
(1) Grep the HTML content using  InnerHtml, use a regular expression like @"<([^>]+)/?]>" to search for arbitrary start/end HTML tags, replace all occurrences  - except those you want to keep - by whitespace.

(2) "Dive" into the HTML structure of your expression, apply InnerHtml/Innertext on sub-elements where appropriate, combine the results.